# "Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration"?

Tags: maven, command-line, automated-tests, testng, surefire

Please excuse the newb question - my conceptual models are still quite incomplete...

I'm trying to re-execute TestNG tests from a command line using maven and surefire. My command line looks like:

```
D:\workspaces\workspace01\aptest>mvn clean install surefire:test -Dtests=myTestNGSuite test
```

Clearly I'm not getting it because the output I end up with includes:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ aptest ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
```

How do I clear out the configuration so I can re-run my TestNG suite from the command line? Is there a better way to run TestNG suites from the command line?

TIA,
-->Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test goal of the surefire plugin is automatically run in the test phase so the first time just run

```
 mvn clean install -Dtest=MyTestNGTest
```

and then if you want to re run do a

```
mvn install -Dtest=MyTestNGTest
```

Note that I am not calling the clean goal so that only your changes of test cases or code are recompiled and that I am NOT invoking the test goal of the surefire plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the command you've given

```
mvn clean install surefire:test -Dtests=myTestNGSuite test
```

BTW: Where the parameter **tests** should be named *[test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test)*

which means to run through the install [life-cycl](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)e which means to run through the following steps:

- validate
- initialize,
- generate-sources,
- process-sources,
- generate-resources,
- process-resources,
- compile,
- process-classes,
- generate-test-sources,
- process-test-sources,
- generate-test-resources,
- process-test-resources,
- test-compile,
- process-test-classes,
- test,
- prepare-package,
- package,
- pre-integration-test,
- integration-test,
- post-integration-test,
- verify,
- install

as you can see that within this life-cycle the *test phase* has already been run...in Other words the **surefire:test** does not make sense nor the **test** which would run the life-cycle like this:

- validate
- initialize,
- generate-sources,
- process-sources,
- generate-resources,
- process-resources,
- compile,
- process-classes,
- generate-test-sources,
- process-test-sources,
- generate-test-resources,
- process-test-resources,
- test-compile,
- process-test-classes,
- test,

So to run the suite within TestNG it is sufficient to call Maven like this:

```
mvn -Dtest=myTestNGSuite test
```

or if you have run the test life cylce before this can be shortent to:

```
mvn -Dtest=myTestNGSuite surefire:test
```

Furthermore usually you shouldn't use test suites neither in JUnit nor in TestNG cause maven-surefire-plugin will automatically recognize the unit tests within the correct locaiton (src/test/java). so there is no need to write Test Suites. BTW you should define an more up-to-date version of the maven-surefire-plugin (2.13 in the meantime).

Comment: What this answer tells me is how much information I've skipped over in getting some utility from Maven. I got things to work again by going simpler, that's what I needed to do for now. Thanks!