# Maven with cucumber and selenium shows 0 runs tests

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber-junit

I have an application that does integration tests with selenium and cucumber
When I perform a

```
 mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @test" -Dbrowser=chrome -P dev
```

The tests are running fine but at the end, while generating the surefire report I get the message of 0 run tests “Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration”. I am not using as life-cycle step install and do not use TestNG.

This is my POM-file

```
<groupId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</groupId>
<artifactId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<properties>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <selenium-java.version>3.4.0</selenium-java.version>
    <cucumber-junit.version>1.2.4</cucumber-junit.version>
    <cucumber-java8.version>1.2.4</cucumber-java8.version>
    <cucumber-reports.version>1.0.7</cucumber-reports.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>2.10.4</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
    <jasypt.version>1.8</jasypt.version>
    <json-simple.version>1.1.1</json-simple.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-java8.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-reports.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>${jasypt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--JSON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${json-simple.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources/properties</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <test-data>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</test-data>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>pilot</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <test-data>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</test-data>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <test-data>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</test-data>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105820/skipping-execution-of-surefire-because-it-has-already-been-run-for-this-configu)

Comment: I am not performing an 'install' or 'package'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the pom like this:
The problems war: there were multiple profiles selected active as default, changed the cucumber-reports from mkolisnyk to cucumber-reporting from masterthought because the mkolisnyk was conflicting with maven reports.

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <selenium-java.version>3.4.0</selenium-java.version>
        <cucumber-junit.version>1.2.4</cucumber-junit.version>
        <cucumber-java8.version>1.2.4</cucumber-java8.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.20</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.0.0-M1</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
        <cucumber-reporting.version>1.4.0</cucumber-reporting.version>
        <cukedoctor-converter.version>1.0.6</cukedoctor-converter.version>
        <jasypt.version>1.8</jasypt.version>
        <json-simple.version>1.1.1</json-simple.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber-junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber-java8.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>${jasypt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JSON-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${json-simple.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/resources/properties</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.cukedoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>cukedoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFileName>documentation</outputFileName>
                    <outputDir>docs</outputDir>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <toc>left</toc>
                    <numbered>true</numbered>
                    <docVersion>1.0</docVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <test-data>testprofiles/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json</test-data>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>pilot</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <test-data>testprofiles/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json</test-data>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <test-data>testprofiles/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json</test-data>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qa</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <test-data>testprofiles/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json</test-data>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>localhost</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <test-data>testprofiles/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json</test-data>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```